# How can I disable hide action in navigation bar on keyboard appears?

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard, uitoolbar

when I try to search something in my application searchbar inside toolbar in navigation controller, the keyboard appears and hides my toolbar until the keyboard is visible. If I hide the keyboard the toolbar returns visible.

How can I disable all of these thing?!?

I need to set my toolbar always visible, even if the keyboard is showed.

Comment: Toolbar is at bottom of view?

Comment: your searchbar is on navigation bar?

Comment: I have a UIToolbar, not a NavigationBar. So I added my UIToolbar to the view

`[self.view addSubview:_toolBar];`

And then I setted the dimensions based on navigation controller bar

`[self.toolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];`

Comment: @Bruno : Screen shot will explain your situation with bit more clarity

Comment: Made it. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is what happen
[image]

And this is how I set my toolbar in my controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     _tempDataSource = [_dataSource mutableCopy];

     [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, _toolBar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-_toolBar.frame.size.height)];
     [self.view addSubview:_toolBar];

     if (iOS7) {
          [self.toolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1, 44, 44)];
     }
     else
     {
          [self.toolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
     }
}
```